# how to save many to many field using django custom forms

Tags: django, many-to-many

how can i save many courses to the student table .I want to keep my design like this.This code is not saving the many to many field(courses) through AddStudentForm.It returns an error with courses variable.If i used CharField instead of ManyToManyField in models for courses then the code works perfectly,but when i use ManyToManyField then it is not working.
it throws courses when i used form.errors .If i didn't use form.errors then it doesn't give any error neither saves the data.

how can i save many courses to the student table .I want to keep my design like this.This code is not saving the many to many field(courses) through AddStudentForm.It returns an error with courses variable.

> models.py

```
class Course(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    duration = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    courses = models.ManyToManyField(Course)
    email = models.EmailField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='Students',blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

> forms.py

```
class AddStudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # courses = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, queryset=Course.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ['name','courses','email','image']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AddStudentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields["courses"].widget = CheckboxSelectMultiple()
        self.fields["courses"].queryset = Course.objects.all()
```

> views.py

```
def addstudent(request):
    courses = Course.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddStudentForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            student = form.save(commit=False)
            course = form.cleaned_data['courses']
            student.courses = course
            student.save()
            # student.courses.add(course)
            # student.save_m2m()
            # student.courses.set(course) # this method also didn't helped me

            messages.success(request, 'student with name  {}  added.'.format(student.name))
            return redirect('students:add_student')
        else:
            # messages.error(request,'Error in form.Try again')
            return HttpResponse(form.errors) # this block is called and returns courses
    else:
        form = AddStudentForm()
    return render(request,'students/add_student.html',{'form':form,'courses':courses})
```

> add_student.html

```
                <form action="{% url 'students:add_student' %}" 
                  method="post" 
                 enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <h5>Full Name <span class="text-danger">*</span> 
                       </h5>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text" name="name" class="form- 
                control" > </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <h5>Courses<span class="text-danger">*</span> 
                      </h5>
                    <div class="controls">
                     {% for course in courses %}
                     <input name ="courses" type="checkbox" id="course- 
                   {{course.id}}" value="{{course.title}}">
                     <label for="course-{{course.id}}">{{course.title}} 
                           </label>
                     {% endfor %} # i think the problem is here.
                   </div>
                    </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                        <h5>Email <span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text" name="email" class="form- 
                      control" required> </div>
                    </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <h5>Image <span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
                        <div class="controls">
                        <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control" > </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="text-xs-right">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Add</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: Have you tried doing `student.courses.add(course)` yet?

Comment: Can you post the error you are getting?

Comment: i just tried that.still not workiing

Comment: it does not give any errors.so i returned form.errors and it returned courses

Comment: I agree, I think the problem is in how you're showing courses in the template.  Can I suggest you simply user `{{form}}` to display all the fields and get the view working with that first.  Then you can see how django is formatting the courses element in the template and replicate with your formatting

Comment: when i simply used {{form}} then i got no options to select ManyToManyField(courses).It just displaying the courses i added.but there is not selecting options

Comment: It looks like you are setting the value of the input for courses to be the `course.title`.  Is that what you are trying to save into the `Student` class?  I would think the `Student` class would need the full `Course` object.  Unless you are getting the course object when you clean the data.  Have you tried explicitly grabbing a course object, adding it to your `student.courses` list and then saving?  Without taking any user input to make sure that's working?

Comment: yes i am trying to save courses.title in the student class.

Comment: Michael Platt please help me to solve this

Comment: Try instead of doing this `student.courses = course` do something like `student.courses.add(courses[0])` and see if that saves.  If it does, it means you have to include the whole `Course` object when you add it to the student's list of courses, not just the title.

Comment: it didn't worked either

Comment: Can you put in a break point and walk through the code and see which line you are getting the error on?  It's hard to say much more without additional information.

Comment: i think the error is in template or in forms.py please look at their once.Before i was using charfield instead of manytomanyfield and it was working fine but after changing and migrating to manytomany it is not saving the data

Comment: Why do you think it's there?  If the page is loading with no errors on the page it shouldn't be a problem within the template.

Comment: i don't know that's the code all i have .should i have to use charfield again

Answer (score 2):

You need to save first before you can assign m2m, the system needs the primary key of the Student model before it can insert into the m2m table.

```
if form.is_valid():
            student = form.save(commit=False)
            course = form.cleaned_data['courses']            
            student.save()

            # this will save by itself
            student.courses.set(course)
```

Comment: are you sure the cleaned_data['courses'] has the proper data?

Comment: yes when i used charfield instead of manytomanyfield.it was working fine.after i changed and migrated to manyfield it is not working

Comment: Try student = form.save(commit=True), then you don't need to save() manually, this will take care of m2m too.

Comment: You don't need the `*` on `student.courses.set(*course)`, since the `.set()` method accepts querysets (Actually will throw an error with the `*` because of querysets being converted into multiple arguments). Sorry to be picky but it might help someone in the future.